# Change the class name based on key on react

Tags: reactjs

I would like to change the class name of my list items based on information passed on keys. But obviously I am doing something wrong.

On every click I like to update the state with key then based on this state I would like to set the class name as active and active CSS should change the style of the list item

```js
class Header extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = {
     activeIndex: 0
    }
    this.ChangeColor = this.ChangeColor.bind(this);
  }
  
  ChangeColor(key) {
  this.setState({
   activeIndex: key
  })
  console.log(this.state.activeIndex)
  }
  
  render() {
     return (
   <div id='header' >
   <a href="#default" className="logo">CompanyLogo</a>
    <div id='buttons' >
      <li key = {0} className={this.state.activeIndex==0 ? 'active' : null } onClick = {this.ChangeColor} >Home</li>
      <li key = {1} className={this.state.activeIndex==1 ? 'active' : null } onClick = {this.ChangeColor} >Features</li>
      <li key = {2} className={this.state.activeIndex==2 ? 'active' : null } onClick = {this.ChangeColor}  >How It Works</li>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
  }
}


class App extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
   super(props)
  }
  
  render() {
   return(
    <div>
      <Header />
    </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
#header {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f4f4f4;
  padding: 20px 10px;
}

#buttons{
  float:right;
}

#buttons > .active {
    background-color: #008CBA; /* Green */
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 2px
}

#buttons > li {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #008CBA;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 2px
}

#buttons > li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that your program doesn't work is that you are not passing any key when you call `ChangeColor`. Hence, after the first click your `activeIndex` will be undefined. You need to modify these three lines, as shown below, to ensure `ChangeColor` knows the key of the item that is clicked. Please notice that you cannot call the function directly like this `this.ChangeColor(0)`.

```
  <li key={0} className={this.state.activeIndex == 0 ? 'active' : null} onClick={() => this.ChangeColor(0)} >Home</li>
  <li key={1} className={this.state.activeIndex == 1 ? 'active' : null} onClick={() => this.ChangeColor(1)} >Features</li>
  <li key={2} className={this.state.activeIndex == 2 ? 'active' : null} onClick={() => this.ChangeColor(2)}  >How It Works</li>
```

Comment: I see. I thought putting key={0} would solve my problem and gets this key automatically but obviously not. thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the key/index into the change color function for each item

`onClick = {() => this.ChangeColor(0)}`

`onClick = {() => this.ChangeColor(1)}`

etc..

then what you have done should work